# python: remove the farthest left instance matching regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like

```
xp = /dir/dir/dir[2]/dir/dir[5]/dir
```

I want

```
xp = /dir/dir/dir[2]/dir/dir/dir
```

`xp.replace(r'\[([^]]*)\]', '')` removes all the square brackets, I just want to remove the one on the far left.

IT should also completely ignore square brackets with `not(random_number_of_characters)`

ex `/dir/dir/dir[2]/dir/dir[5]/dir[1][not(random_number_of_characters)]`

should yield `/dir/dir/dir[2]/dir/dir[5]/dir[not(random_number_of_characters)]`

ex. `/dir/dir/dir[2]/dir/dir[5]/dir[not(random_number_of_characters)]`

should yield `/dir/dir/dir[2]/dir/dir/dir[not(random_number_of_characters)]`

Comment: did you want to remove the last `[]` brackets?

Comment: Is there always one or more digits between the brackets that needs to be removed, ie. `'/dir/dir/dir[2]/dir/dir[5]/dir'` becomes `'/dir/dir/dir[2]/dir/dir/dir'`, but `'/dir/dir/dir[2]/dir/dir[A]/dir'` is unchanged?

Answer (score 2):

This code would remove the last square brackets,

```
>>> import re
>>> xp = "/dir/dir/dir[2]/dir/dir[5]/dir"
>>> m = re.sub(r'\[[^\]]*\](?=[^\[\]]*$)', r'', xp)
>>> m
'/dir/dir/dir[2]/dir/dir/dir'
```

A lookahead is used to check whether the square brackets are followed by any character not of `[`, `]` symbols zero or more times upto the line end. So it helps to match the last `[]` brackets. Then replacing the matched brackets with an empty string would completely remove the last brackets.

**UPDATE:**

You could try the below regex also,

```
\[[^\]]*\](?=(?:[^\[\]]*\[not\(.*?\)\]$))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zI7xF3/3)

Comment: How would you make an exception so that it doesn't remove a square bracket that contains `not(random_characters)` ex. '/dir/dir/dir[2]/dir/dir[5]/dir[not(random)]` should yield '/dir/dir/dir[2]/dir/dir/dir[not(random)]`

Comment: you mean the not `[` folowed by not or did you want skip the `[]` which contains `()`?

Comment: I want to skip the entire `[not(randomcharcters)]`, I Added an example in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Make it greedy and replace with captured groups.

```
                   (.*)\[[^]]*\](.*)
 Greedy Group ------^^  ^^^^^^^^-------- Last bracket [ till ]
```

Replacement : `$1$2` or `\1\2`

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/kF2cK6/1)

sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(.*)\[[^]]*\](.*)')
test_str = u"xp = /dir/dir/dir[2]/dir/dir[5]/dir"
subst = u"$1$2"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Comment: Smart use of greediness !

Comment: if a square bracket has values like [not(randomcharacters)], can you make it skip that entire square bracket? I want to ignore square brackets with `[not(randomcharacters)]`

Comment: Shouldn't the replacement string be `ur'\1\2'` ? i.e. backreferences?

Comment: @user299709 it means if `[]` contains `()` then don't remove it. right?

Comment: @mhawke the code is copied from demo site. No idea about Python. Let me mention it in the post as well. Thanks.

Comment: @user3218114 - regex101 accepts either \ or `$`, but it should be \.